# Caddy: Rewrite path to URL parameter

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

I am currently using Caddy as a reverse proxy.

```
rewrite / /index.html
```

`https://localhost/` --> `https://localhost/index.html`

`https://localhost/?p1=v1&p2=v2` --> `https://localhost/index.html?p1=v1&p2=v2`

Now I want to additionally change the path `/static` to `index.html`. However, a URL parameter `static=true` should then be added.

`https://localhost/static` --> `https://localhost/index.html?static=true`

This additional URL parameter should not influence the existing parameters.

`https://localhost/static?p1=v1&p2=v2` --> `https://localhost/index.html?static=true&p1=v1&p2=v2`

**How do I have to adjust my caddyfile to make this work as desired?** I just tried the following, but unfortunately it didn't work.

```
rewrite /static /index.html?static=true
```

Answer (score 1):

`{query}` is the old query params,so can do like this:

```
rewrite /static index.html?{query}&static=true
```

the documents: [placeholders](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/concepts#placeholders)